# How can I iterate over an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this JSON structure:

```
const arr = [
        {
          id: "TaskStatuses",
          rows: [
            {id: "1", name: "Success"},
            {id: "2", name: "Error"},
          ]
        },
        {
          id: "Objects",
          rows: [
            {id: "1", name: "Object1"},
            {id: "2", name: "Object2"},
          ]
        },
        {
          id: "Groups",
          rows: [
            {id: "1", name: "Group1"},
            {id: "2", name: "Group2"},
          ]
        },
      ]
```

I need to create array with some condition. If my condition correctly I will push elements arr.rows.

Finally i want to get this structure:

```
[
{
  Objects: "Object1",
  Groups: "Group1"
},
  {
    Objects: "Object2",
    Groups: "Group2"
  }
]
```

I try to do like this

```
let sites = []
    for (let el in arr) {
            if (arr.id == "Objects") {
              for (let item of el.rows) {
                sites.push({Objects: item.name})
              }
            }
            if (arr.id == "Groups") {
              for (let item of el.rows) {
                sites.Groups = item.name
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Ivar Sorry, I added images as I am having problems with text formatting. Only now I realized how stupid this is.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted properties in new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "TaskStatuses", rows: [{ id: "1", name: "Success" }, { id: "2", name: "Error" }] }, { id: "Objects", rows: [{ id: "1", name: "Object1" }, { id: "2", name: "Object2" }] }, { id: "Groups", rows: [{ id: "1", name: "Group1" }, { id: "2", name: "Group2" }] }],
    ids = ['Objects', 'Groups'],
    result = data.reduce((r, { id, rows }) => ids.includes(id)
        ? rows.map(({ name }, i) => ({ ...r[i], [id]: name }))
        : r,
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```